# PHP 8 Comments bug

Tags: php, debugging, php-8

In previous version of PHP we have code comments written like

```
#[Socket panel]
```

After Updating to PHP 8 we are getting Error

```
syntax error, unexpected identifier "panel", expecting "]"
```

Is this bug in new PHP 8 or i am missing something ? Is there any solution to support older comment.

Comment: Those are not comments in PHP 8 but attributes [attributes](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#attributes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a hash sign (#) for commenting in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093609/can-i-use-a-hash-sign-for-commenting-in-php)

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate has been updated to reflect on attributes.

Comment: Got it, find and replace all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 8 you have now Attributes which are used in the following style `#[Testclass]` this is why you get this error.

https://stitcher.io/blog/attributes-in-php-8

You have to change that comments to another style.

Comment: I missed this change

Answer (score 1):

As of the new PHP 8, those aren't comments, they're Attributes.

They've changed the Attribute syntax from `<<attr>>` to `#[attr]`. (See [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shorter_attribute_syntax).)

Comment: Actually, the result of that RFC was a change from `<<attr>>` to `@@attr`; there was then [_yet another RFC_](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shorter_attribute_syntax_change) which changed it to `#[attr]` after a long debate and about a dozen different suggestions. But that was all before 8.0.0, so all anyone needs to know is that `#[attr]` is the syntax that actually got "released".